# Windows 8.1 + Vagrant - Connection Refused - Makes me want to cry

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, vagrant

I've spent two days chasing my tails with Vagrant. Under no circumstances can I connect from my Windows 8.1 host machine to the VM, not through the browser, nor with Putty.

Even doing a simple `vagrant init ubuntu/precise32` (also tried with trusty64 and trusty32), then `vagrant up`, Vagrant spins up the VM, but I then just get multiple `default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...`.

I CAN connect to my other, non-Vagrant, VMs. I can also ping domains like google from with my Vagrant provisioned VMs, so I know the VM can connect to the network and outside world.

However networking really isn't my forte, so *please* can someone help me debug this issue!